# Understanding output of logical AND exercise

Tags: boolean, logic

I am working on an exercise with the instructions:

> Write a program that performs Logical AND operation on two numbers.

and accompanied is this example of input and output:

```
Enter the 1st number:12
Enter the 2nd number:6
Result is 4
```

I do not understand how an `AND` comparison of these two numbers returns the output of 4. I keep thinking the output couldn't be anything other than 0, as the two numbers are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is badly written; they mean bitwise and (`&`).

```
>>> print(12 & 6)
4
```

To understand why, you must look at the binary values:

```
  1100     (12)
  0110     ( 6)
& ----
  0100     ( 4)
```

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot morse sense. Thanks for the help!